# Output file is not creating a single gap after header

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am generating a text file using my C# application and i am wondering why my output is **not giving me a single row gap after the header row**. Well, my input text file does have this single row gap but after the conversion i couldn't see this single row gap. Please help me out.

Code snippet:-

```
public void just_create_text()
{
    //Here we are exporting header
    string[] strLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
    string CarouselName = enter.Text;
    int[] cols = new int[] { 15, 15, 25, 15, 15 };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string line = RemoveWhiteSpace(strLines[0]).Trim();
    string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');

    for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
        sb.Append(cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(cols[c])); 
     // here i am replacing the space with underscore...

    sb.Append("Location".PadRight(15));
    sb.Append("\r\n");

    int tmpCarousel = 0;
    int carouselNumber = 0;
    Dictionary<string, int> namesForCarousels = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < textfile.Count; i++)
    {
         for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
         sb.Append(textfile[i].Cells[c].Replace(" ","_").PadRight(cols[c]));

        string name = textfile[i].Cells[1];

        if (namesForCarousels.TryGetValue(name, out tmpCarousel) == false)
        {
            carouselNumber++;
            namesForCarousels[name] = carouselNumber;
        }
        var strCorousel = lstMX.Find(x => x.MAX_PN.Equals(name)).Carousel;
        strCorousel = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strCorousel)) ? CarouselName : strCorousel;
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0}:{1}", strCorousel, carouselNumber).PadRight(15));

        sb.Append("\r\n");
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\output.TXT", sb.ToString());
}

private string RemoveWhiteSpace(string str)
{
    str = str.Replace("  ", " ");
    if (str.Contains("  "))
        str = RemoveWhiteSpace(str);
    return str;
}
```

Input text file: its just a .txt format

```
Designator  MAX PN  Footprint   Center-X(mm)    Center-Y(mm)

"AC1"   "100-0177"  "CAPC1608N" "7.239" "82.677"
"AC2"   "100-0177"  "CAPC1608N" "4.445" "85.471"
"C1"   "100-0211"  "0805M - CAPACITOR" "14.745"    "45.72"
"C2"   "100-0230"  "CAPC3225N" "83.388"    "58.42"
"C3"   "100-0145"  "CAPC1608N" "101.543"   "73.025"
"C10"  "100-0145"  "CAPC1608N" "109.163"   "73.025"
```

In output text file i need like below

```
 Designator     MAX_PN         Footprint                Center-X(mm)   Center-Y(mm)   Location   
                   // <<Here is the single gap>>    
 C66            100-0009       0805M_-_CAPACITOR        90.106         39.37          eeee:1         
 C24            100-0009       0805M_-_CAPACITOR        64.973         24.067         eeee:1         
 C25            100-0009       0805M_-_CAPACITOR        106.553        45.657         eeee:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you thought you'd get a blank line in the first place. But try adding another line to the output here:

```
sb.Append("Location".PadRight(15));
sb.Append("\r\n");
sb.Append("\r\n");
```

Even better, use the sb.AppendLine() method instead:

```
sb.AppendLine("Location".PadRight(15));
sb.AppendLine();
```

Comment: Also have a look to this <https://imageshack.com/i/f0tIFW6Dj> and this past:- please http://pastie.org/9701782